# Errors in Spring STS servlet-context.xml file

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

Iam new to java and spring. STS version is 3.1.0.RELEASE.

Iam getting follwoing error in  "servlet-context.xml" file.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean]
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
- Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] Offending resource: file [D:/springy/roo/t03/src/main/
 webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
```

Errors are on these entries in xml file :

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
```

Following is servlet-context.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.foo.bar" />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />       
</beans:beans>
```

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Comment: Can you share the entire xml file

Comment: @Arun P Johny!  It is full servlet-context.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix the `bean` element with `beans:`

ex:

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />
```

It is because you have imported the `bean` element with the [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) `beans`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property  name="viewClass" value= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions" >
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```